# Passing data from child to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I was reading a tutorial on Medium that explained how to pass data from a child component to parent (https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17).  The tutorial got 5.5k likes, which means many people must've used it as a reference in their own work.  However, upon replicating the code 1:1, I was completely unable to  to get the same results.  In fact, data wasn't being passed from the child to the parent at all.  Plus, when I forced data to pass up, I got an infinite loop.  I would greatly appreciate if anyone can point out where I am wrong, or if in fact, it is the tutorial after all.

JS fiddle to my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/lightspeed12/69z2wepo/216279/

```js
class ToDoItem extends React.Component {
  someFn = () => {
    let listInfo = 'Hi mom'
    this.props.callBackFromParent(listInfo);
  }
  render(){return <h3>Hello World</h3>}
};

class ToDoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      listDataFromChild: null
    }
  }
  
  myCallback = (dataFromChild) => {
    this.setState({ listDataFromChild : dataFromChild })
  }
  
  otherFn = () => {
      console.log(this.state.listDataFromChild, 'from state')
  }
  
  render(){
   this.otherFn();  //calling otherFn to determine value of this.state.listDataFromChild
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Message from Child is:</h2>
       
        <ToDoItem 
          callBackFromParent={this.myCallback}
        />  
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ToDoList />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.someFn()` of `ToDoItem` is never executed.

Try:

```
// To-do Item.
class ToDoItem extends React.Component {

  // Render.
  render = () => <h3>Hello World</h3>

  // Did Mount.
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.callBackFromParent('Callback Received.')
  }

}
```

See below for a practical example of a `functional prop` being `passed` and `executed`.

```js
// Parent.
class Parent extends React.Component {

  // State.
  state = {data: null}
  
  // Callback.
  callback = data => this.setState({data})
  
  // Render.
  render(){
    const {data} = this.state
    console.log('Data:', data)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>Parent</h2>
        <Child callback={this.callback}/>
        Data: {data || 'null'}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
  
}

// Child.
const Child = props => <button onClick={() => props.callback('Callback Received.')}>Child.</button>

// Mount.
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>,document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Got it, but what if I don't want to attach the render of ToDoItem to an event? In other words, must an event occur in order for some data to be passed from a child to parent?

Comment: In that case: you could leverage a `lifecycle method` such as [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) or [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) @MiddleZ

Comment: See above for an example @MiddleZ

Answer (score 0):

`this.someFn()` of ToDoItem is never called ,which calls the callback method to ToDoList component. Here `this.someFn()`  is called  on a button click.

```
    class ToDoItem extends React.Component {
      someFn = () => {
        let listInfo = 'Hi mom'
        this.props.callBackFromParent(listInfo);
      }
       componentDidMount() {
          this.someFn()
  }
  render(){return <h3>Hello World</h3>}
};
```

Data from child can be viewed as

```
  render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>Message from Child is:{this.state.listDataFromChild}</h2>

            <ToDoItem 
              callBackFromParent={this.myCallback}
            />  
          </div>
        )
      }
```

Comment: Got it, but what if I don't want to attach the render of `ToDoItem` to an event?  In other words, must an event occur in order for some data to be passed from a child to parent?

Comment: You can call the callback method on componentDidMount if you don't want to bind an event